# error in insertdata database

Tags: java, android, database

please help me for my problem now, In my activities there are two errors , the first in insertdata

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            db.open();
            db.insertData(editNama.getText().toString()), cekPria.isChecked(), cekWanita.isChecked(),
            editTanggal.getText().toString();
            db.close();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Data telah disimpan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            editNama.setText("");
            cekPria.setChecked(false);
            cekWanita.setChecked(false);
            editTanggal.setText("");

        }
    });
```

and a second error in the "variable 'kelamin' might not have been initialized". I give the sign // place the error

```
public void tampilkanData(){
    db.open();
    Cursor c =db.getAllData();

    ArrayList<String> larik = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            int idArtis = c.getInt(0);
            String namaArtis = c.getString(1);
            int genderPria = c.getInt(2);
            int genderWanita = c.getInt(3);
            String tgLahir = c.getString(4);

            String kelamin;
            if (genderPria == 1){
                kelamin = "Pria";
            }else if (genderWanita == 1){
                kelamin = "Wanita";
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Isi Salah Satu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //larik.add(Integer.toString(idArtis) + ": " + namaArtis + " (" + kelamin + ") -" + tgLahir);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, larik);
    listViewData.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

this is a code insertData()

```
public long insertData(String nama, boolean gender, String tanggal){
    try {
        ContentValues dataBaru = new ContentValues();
        dataBaru.put(Konstanta.NAMA_ARTIS, nama);
        dataBaru.put(Konstanta.GENDER_ARTIS_PRIA, gender);
        dataBaru.put(Konstanta.GENDER_ARTIS_WANITA, gender);
        dataBaru.put(Konstanta.TGLAHIR, tanggal);

        return db.insert(Konstanta.NAMA_TABEL, null, dataBaru);
    }catch (SQLiteException e){
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: About the first one it could be just a problem of brackets. Change `String kelamin;` with `String kelamin = nulll;` to fix the second one

Answer (score -1):

**Error 1:**

This statement is wrong. Should end with `;`. Also, looks like misplaced brackets `)`.

```
db.insertData(editNama.getText().toString()), cekPria.isChecked(), cekWanita.isChecked(),
```

*Wild guess:* This should be

```
db.insertData(editNama.getText().toString(), cekPria.isChecked(), cekWanita.isChecked());
```

If you post the code of `insertData`, we can help your better.

**Error 2**

Change

```
String kelamin;
```

with

`String kelamin = null;` or `String kelamin = "";` as per your needs

Comment: I've followed the instructions in insert data into a problem like this 'db.insertData(editNama.getText().toString(), cekPria.isChecked(), cekWanita.isChecked(),
                editTanggal.getText().toString());' but be an error with the statment "inserData ( ) inDbase can not be applied to :"

Comment: @vianmarles: What is this?